# How to show a UIPageViewController only once on first launch

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsuserdefaults, uipageviewcontroller

I want to show a tutorial that is a UIPageView only once at the beginning of the first launch.

I am attempting this using this code

```
let launchedBefore = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "launchedBefore")
    if launchedBefore  {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "tutorialtohome1", sender: nil)
    }
    else {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "launchedBefore")
    }
```

For some reason it's not working with the UIPageController, it works fine with other views.

Just to make clear, I only want this view to appear once, then never again, as it acts as a tutorial.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Where do you set the value for key "launchedBefore" ?

Comment: Do you want to fire the segue on first launch or after the first launch?

Comment: I want the segue to perform after the first launch, so to skip the tutorial

Answer (score 3):

You need to check the OBJECT. Not the bool. This is better way to do it. On first run, there are no such key "lauchedBefore". You cannot check boolean value of what's not there.

```
let launchedBefore = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "launchedBefore")

    if (launchedBefore==nil)  {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "tutorialtohome1", sender: nil)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "launchedBefore")
    }
    else {
        // already launched, so do nothing.
    }
```

Comment: This is a good answer. Khoury, your logic isn't right, but this code should work. (Voted)

Comment: `boolForKey` doesn't return an optional; it will return `false` if the key isn't defined in user defaults.  It isn't clear from the question, whether the segue should be fired on first launch or after first launch.